# Plugin outputs content of posts unbidden!

Tags: plugin-development

I've written my first plugin. The intent is to show the image, title and excerpt of the first 6 posts. (It uses a function from Divi, here and there).

```
function jm_blog_layout($atts) {

    ob_start();

    echo '<div class="featured-posts">';

    query_posts(array('category_name' => "", 'posts_per_page' => "6"));

    $post_index = 0;

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    $thumbnail_image = get_thumbnail($width = 333)["thumb"];
    $post_id = get_the_id();
    $post_class = 'featured-post';
    if ($post_index == 3) {
        $post_class = $post_class.' focus-post';
    }

    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
    echo '<div class="'.$post_class.'" id="post-'.$post_id.'"style="background-image: url('.$thumbnail_image.');">';
    echo '<div class="overlay">';
    echo '<div class="transformable">';
    echo '<h2 class="vertical-align">'.get_the_title().'</h2>';
    echo '<h3 class="thumb-excerpt">'.get_the_excerpt().'</h3>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';

    $post_index += 1;
    endwhile;

    echo '</div>';

    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;

}
```

It outputs what I want, followed, strangely, by all of the content (i.e the body of text) of the 6 posts I queried - structured like so:

```
<article id="post-84" class="post-84 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-tips">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>...</p>
    </div> <!-- .entry-content -->
</article>
```

It is not part of my page design, nor of my code. Where could it be coming from?

Comment: Never use `query_posts()`, use `WP_Query()` instead. [Here is why](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/22728).

Comment: Oh. It just wraps a big fat global instance? Ewww. Somebody, sometime thought this was a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

I found it is coming from `wp-content/themes/Divi/page-template-blank.php`, which is my parent template. I concluded the mutable handwaving of `wp_query` was confusing the template and, after a search, found [this neat flowchart](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) letting me know I should call `wp_reset_query`. That fixed it.